# JPA OneToMany and ManyToOne: Error NULL not allowed for column

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many, many-to-one

I'm using JPA with hibernate as provider. There are two entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PROYECTOS")
public class Proyecto {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "proyecto", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Incidencia> incidencias;
    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "INCIDENCIAS")
public class Incidencia {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    ...
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_PROYECTO", nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private Proyecto proyecto;
    ...
    public Incidencia(Proyecto proyecto, Usuario usuario, String descripcion,
        Date fechaYHora) {
        super();
        this.proyecto = proyecto;
        this.usuario = usuario;
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
        this.fechaYHora = fechaYHora;
    }
    ...
}
```

When I execute a test method and try to persist "Incidencia" class ("Proyecto" was persisted before):

```
...
entityManager.persist(proyecto);
entityManager.flush();
...
Incidencia incidencia = new Incidencia(proyectoFind, usuario,
                "1ª incidencia del proyecto", new Date());
proyecto.getIncidencias().add(incidencia);
entityManager.persist(proyecto);
entityManager.flush();
...
```

An exception is thrown from the last flush:

```
    ... 35 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcBatchUpdateException: La columna "PROYECTO" no permite valores nulos (NULL)
NULL not allowed for column "PROYECTO"; SQL statement:
insert into INCIDENCIAS (DESCRIPCION, FECHA_Y_HORA, ID_PROYECTO, ID_USUARIO, ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23502-175]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeBatch(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:1167)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
    ... 41 more
```

I'm sure that "proyecto" is set in "Incidencia" because in its constructor:

```
this.proyecto = proyecto;
```

So, I can't understand why this exception is thrown.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked that `proyectoFind` has a non-null value?

Comment: You **must** use proper english words for your variables and classes. It's pain in the a** to read your code !!!

Comment: I'm sorry I don't use english words for variables and classes in this question. It's my first question and I haven't taken care of this matter. I'll try to use English words for everything in next questions.
I checked that "proyecto" (what I called "proyectoFind" by mistake) doesn't have a null value.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you list all the columns in the database table INCIDENCIAS? The error indicates a problem with a column called PROYECTO, not ID_PROYECTO.

Comment: The exception says: Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcBatchUpdateException: La columna "PROYECTO" no permite valores nulos (NULL)
NULL not allowed for column "PROYECTO"; SQL statement:
insert into INCIDENCIAS (USUARIO_CREACION, FECHA_CREACION, DESCRIPCION, FECHA_Y_HORA, USUARIO_ULTIMA_MODIFICACION, FECHA_ULTIMA_MODIFICACION, ID_PROYECTO, ID_USUARIO, VERSION, ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23502-175]. The columns that apear in the sentence are the same that I defined in the class. The column PROYECTO is not defined in the class. For you information I'm using an in-memory database H2.

Comment: What happens if you remove the calls to flush?

Comment: The exception is still thrown. It doesn't matter when it executes the inserts in de DB. Whenever it tries to insert Incidencia the exception is thrown. This is the metamodel: id java.lang.Long BASIC
fechaYHora java.util.Date BASIC
createdBy java.lang.String BASIC
lastModifiedDate org.joda.time.DateTime BASIC
descripcion java.lang.String BASIC
version int BASIC
createdDate org.joda.time.DateTime BASIC
lastModifiedBy java.lang.String BASIC
usuario com.pericles.cooperativa.gestion.domain.Usuario MANY_TO_ONE
proyecto com.pericles.cooperativa.gestion.domain.Proyecto MANY_TO_ONE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I've been able to solve the problem.
There weren't any problems with the mappings I presented in both classes. Those mappings I showed about Proyecto and Incidencia were different before. The class Incidencia used a compound primary key with an Id class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "INCIDENCIAS")
@IdClass(IncidenciaKey.class)
public class Incidencia implements Serializable { 
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_PROYECTO", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long idProyecto;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @NotNull
    @Valid
    private Proyecto proyecto;
...
}
```

I only renamed this old version of Incidencia, so there were two classes with @Table(name = "INCIDENCIAS"). I suppose this was the mistake. There was still a column named "PROYECTO" in the in-memory database that it came from this renamed and, as I thought incorrectly, unused entity.

As soon as I moved the renamed Incidencia class out of the package from the database is built everything worked properly.

I want to apoligise for asking this inaccurate question.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

After this line

```
proyecto.getIncidencias().add(incidencia);
```

you need to set a back reference on the incidencia object

```
incidencia.setProyecto(proyecto);
```

then flush.

It does not seem correct that you are passing proyectoFind in the constructor for incidencia and then adding the same object to a different Proyecto object.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
I'm sorry but "proyectoFind" was a mistake in the code I wrote. 
I also tried to use the default constructor and set the variables of "Incidencia" instead of using the constructor with arguments.
I also checked that "proyecto" doesn't have a null value.
And I also set a back reference on the incidencia object as you recommended.
But the same exception is thrown.

Comment: So, I use:
Incidencia incidencia = new Incidencia(proyecto, usuario, "1ª incidencia del proyecto", new Date());
Instead of:
Incidencia incidencia = new Incidencia(proyectoFind, usuario, "1ª incidencia del proyecto", new Date());
But the same exception is thrown.

Comment: Is the primary key of proyecto set?

Comment: Yes, it is. After persist proyecto object and flush, I check all the properties of proyecto. All of them are correct and its primary key (id) as well. Then, I create incidencia object with this proyecto, add incidencia to proyecto, set a back reference on the incidencia object (I think, this is redundant) and finally, flush. But the exception is still thrown.